# Check multiple values of multiple keys

Tags: c#, .net

I have a dictionary  as:

```
Dictionary<string, object> person = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

The values in dictionary are like this:

```
person.Add("State", "Florida");
person.Add("Gender", "Male");
person.Add("Married", 1);
person.Add("SalaryUnderHundredDollar", 1)
```

I have to check the above properties of Person and then I have to give some schemes to that person.

I am doing the following:

```
List<int> listOfSchemesEligble = new List<int>();
if(person["State"].ToString() == "Florida" || person["State"].ToString() == "NewYork")
{
   listOfSchemesEligble.Add(100); 
}
if(person["Gender"].ToString() == "Male")
{
   listOfSchemesEligble.Add(110); 
}
if(Convert.ToBoolean(person["Married"]))
{
   listOfSchemesEligble.Add(200); 
}
if(Convert.ToBoolean(person["SalaryUnderHundredDollar"]))
{
   listOfSchemesEligble.Add(500); 
}
```

Is there any better way to do this because I have so many conditions besides these?

Comment: It is better to create a class for `Person` instead of using a `Dictionary`. That alone will not reduce the number of conditions you have to make, but you will not need to do all those type conversions.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you should create a `Person` class, that will hold the properties of a person:

```
public enum GenderType
{
   Male, Female, Unknown
}

public class Person
{
   public int PersonId {get;set;}
   public string State {get;set;}
   public GenderType Gender {get;set;}
   public bool Married {get; set}
   public bool SalaryUnderHundredDollar {get;set}
}
```

Now you can create instances of `Person` class and use them directly, in a strongly-typed fashion:

```
var person = new Person()
{ 
   State = "Florida", 
   Gender = GenderType.Male, 
   Married = true, 
   SalaryUnderHundredDollar = true 
};
if ( person.Married ) ...
```

For more information see [the documentation intro to classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/quick-starts/introduction-to-classes). Classes are the fundamental building block of object-oriented languages, hence it is natural to represent objects from real world as classes with appropriate properties.

### Update

As you mentioned in the comments, your data come from JSON. It seems it is wrapped in double curly braces, but the inner "object" is a `JToken`. You can deserialize a `JToken` to a class as well:

```
var person = personFile.First.ToObject<Person>();
```

The only problem seems that the `Married` and `SalaryUnderHundredDollar` are integers instead of booleans, so you would have to change the type of the properties in the class above to `int`.

Comment: I didnt actually mention how I am filling the dictionary. I am actually filling the dictionary from JToken (from a JSON) like : person = personFile.First.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value); Thats why  I am  directly using the dictionary and checking all the conditions.

Comment: You can then use `JsonConvert.Deserialize<Person>` to convert a JSON object to a class.

Comment: Generally - if you have a JSON you want to deserialize, put it into http://json2csharp.com/ and that will generate a class you can use for deserialization.

Comment: Its actually a Jtoken object not an actual JSON object.And we dont need to seriialize Jtoken object u can directly query this object the way I am doing and converting it into DIctionary

Comment: See an example here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: And what is the value of the `JToken` itself? Could you post the file?

Comment: {{
  "PersonId": 1234,
  "State": "Florida",
  "Gender": "Male",
  "Married ": 1,
  "SalaryUnderHundredDollar ": 1,
 }} This is the structure.We are not maintaining the file.Sent to us by other team in this form.And in this there are hundreds of properties.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to parse the `JToken`

Comment: Ya i got your point but in this way also I have to check all the conditions. And  also have to create the Person class with hundreds of properties.It will also be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation need to be changed. I can imagine below implementation to be better in terms of maintainability + OOP guidelines :

```
public class Person
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public bool Married { get; set; }   
    public bool SalaryUnderHundredDollar { get; set; }
}
public class SchemeBuilder
{
    public List<Func<int>> BuildScheme(Person person)
    {
        return new List<Func<int>>
        {
            ()=> person.State=="Florida" || person.State=="NewYork" ? 100 : 0,
            ()=> person.Gender=="Male" ? 110 : 0,
            ()=>person.Married ? 200 : 0,
            ()=>person.SalaryUnderHundredDollar ? 500 :0
        };
    }
}
public class TestClass
{
    public void Main()
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.State = "NewYork";
        person.Gender = "Female";
        person.Married = true;
        person.SalaryUnderHundredDollar = true;
        List<int> listOfSchemesEligble = new List<int>();
        var builder = new SchemeBuilder();

        var schemes = builder.BuildScheme(person);

        foreach(var scheme in schemes)
        {
            var eleigiblePoints = scheme();
            if (eleigiblePoints != 0)
                listOfSchemesEligble.Add(eleigiblePoints);
        }
    }
}
```

This can be further refactored of course.